# Second order Taylor's series expansion of a function

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion

[image]

I am trying to understand the attached example. The second derivative matrix, not given in the text above works out to

$$\begin{pmatrix} 
2x_{2} & 2x_{1}+5e^{x_{2}} \\
2x_{1}+5e^{x_{2}} & 5x_{1}e^{x_{2}}
\end{pmatrix}$$

My doubt in the attached text is at asterix mark and circled $\theta$ s. As per my understanding instead of $\theta$, it should be $\theta$$x_{2}$ However if the print is correct,I have not understood how.

Will be grateful for help in clarifying this doubt

Answer (score 1):

Your second derivation of $f(x_1,x_2)$ is correct. There are just typos in the book. We obtain

\begin{array}{cccccc|cccccc}
&&f&&&&&&x_1^2x_2+5x_1e^{x_2}\\
&f_{x_1}&&f_{x_2}&&&&2x_1x_2+5e^{x_2}&&x_1^2+5x_1e^{x_2}\\
f_{x_1x_1}&&f_{x_1x_2}&&f_{x_2x_2}&&2x_2&&2x_1+5e^{x_2}&&5x_1e^{x_2}\\
\end{array}

> We calculate the remainder term be evaluating the terms in the last line at
>   \begin{align*}
> (a_1,a_2)+\theta (h_1,h_2)=(1,0)+\theta (h_1,h_2)=(1+\theta h_1,\theta h_2)
> \end{align*}
>   and obtain 
>   \begin{align*}
> &\left(f_{x_1x_1}(x_1,x_2)\frac{h_1^2}{2}+f_{x_1x_2}(x_1,x_2)h_1h_2
> +f_{x_2x_2}(x_1,x_2)\frac{h_2^2}{2}\right)\Bigg|_{(x_1,x_2)=(1+\theta h_1,\theta h_2)}\\
> &\qquad=2(\color{blue}{\theta h_2})\frac{h_1^2}{2}+(2(1+\theta h_1)+5\color{blue}{e^{\theta h_2}})h_1h_2
> +(5(1+\theta  h_1)\color{blue}{e^{\theta h_2}}\frac{h_2^2}{2}
> \end{align*}
>
> Since $(h_1,h_2)=(x_1-1,x_2)$ we conclude the blue parts of the expression are $\color{blue}{\theta h_2=\theta x_2}$ according to OPs calculation.

Comment: Thank you very much... I was not sure if it was a typo error till I got the clarification. Thnx again

Comment: @SAK: You're welcome!